# Template match nodes that have a particular child node - streaming XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I want to select the Worker nodes, that have a Plan child node coming up in Addl_Information section

```
<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Worker[Addl_Information/Plan]">
```

When I use the above code, I get error from Saxon-EE 9.6.0.5 processor saying

```
XTSE3430: Template rule is declared streamable but it does not satisfy the streamability rules. * The match pattern is not motionless
```

What am I doing wrong?

I see examples of (similar) motionless patterns in [w3c site](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#classifying-patterns) but it is not working for me, kindly advise.

**Update**: Here is my stylesheet. I am trying to include only the people who have a record of a certain plan in their worker data. Note, the below `patth` variable was another angle I was trying to evaluate - basically having an IF condition right after, around the remaining code. That also does not work.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="Worker_Sync">
            <File>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Worker"/>    
            </File>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="Worker">
            <xsl:variable name="ThisPerson" select="copy-of()"/> 
            <xsl:variable name="patth" select="Additional_Information/ws:plan"/>
            <xsl:if test="$ThisPerson/$patth">
                <Row>
                    <A1_Account_Number><xsl:value-of select="$ThisPerson/Additional_Information/Account_Number"/></A1_Account_Number>
                    <A2_Employee_Number>...</A2_Employee_Number>
                </Row>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your pattern is similar to `p[b]` of which the spec says "the predicate is not motionless".

Comment: Hmm I think I am starting to get the language. First time making a streaming xslt. Any thoughts on how to implement my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template rule in a streamable mode has to have a motionless match pattern. "Motionless" in this context essentially means that you can evaluate the pattern while the parser is positioned at the element start tag. You can't do that in this case because the predicate tests for the existence of an `Addl_Information` child with a `Plan` grandchild, and you can't tell whether those exist without reading forwards beyond the start tag.

I'm happy to take a look at the stylesheet as a whole to see if I can come up with any suggestions for making it streamable, provided it's reasonably compact.

**==LATER==**

You can use the approach of making a copy of each Worker element when you encounter it, in this case you just need to do all subsequent access within the copied element:

```
<xsl:variable name="ThisPerson" select="copy-of()"/> 
<xsl:if test="$ThisPerson/Additional_Information/ws:plan">
    <Row>
        <A1_Account_Number><xsl:value-of select="$ThisPerson/Additional_Information/Account_Number"/>   </A1_Account_Number>
        <A2_Employee_Number>...</A2_Employee_Number>
    </Row>
</xsl:if>
```

And that is probably the easiest solution. There might be ways of avoiding the copy operation (depending on the exact source document structure), but it will be more complicated, and unless the individual Worker elements are very large, it isn't worth the effort.

Comment: And this is exactly what I used. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use

```
    <xsl:template match="Worker_Sync">
        <File>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="copy-of(Worker)[Addl_Information/Plan]" mode="some-non-streamable-mode"/>    
        </File>
    </xsl:template>
```

then in your template for `Worker` you don't need the test and just

```
    <xsl:template match="Worker" mode="some-non-streamable-mode">
            <Row>
                <A1_Account_Number><xsl:value-of select="Additional_Information/Account_Number"/></A1_Account_Number>
                <A2_Employee_Number>...</A2_Employee_Number>
            </Row>
    </xsl:template>
```